# Responsive Push Nav Menu: Not working for Right Menu (CSS)

Tags: css, navigation, responsive-design

I am following this Codepen by Brad Frost.
http://codepen.io/bradfrost/pen/IEBrz/

However I have a menu on the right.

So I changed

```
.js nav[role=navigation] {
  width: 16em;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -16em;
}
```

to

```
.js nav[role=navigation] {
  width: 16em;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -16em; //this attribute was changed from left to right
}
```

But when I do this the menu does not get hidden.
I get a **horizontal scroll.**
How do I fix this?

You can try it for yourself on Codepen and see.

I can't understand why this won't work.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [TRY THIS][1] [1]: http://callmenick.com/2014/03/26/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change a couple more css attributes:

```
 a.menu-link {
     float: right;
 }
 .js nav[role=navigation] {
   right: -16em;
 }
 .wrap.active {
     right: 0;
 }
```

Comment: I think there is typo in your answer... You have declared styles for .wrap.active twice (using different values for 'right')...
And the problem I am facing is when the menu button is not clicked the  menu is still seen i.e. it is not getting hidden in the first place.